# Lock text highlighting in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, locking, sites

I want to lock the copy button but don't want to lock save as button which is totally right click ,so a user of my site can save the website as a html file but can not copy text ,How can I do it with Javascript guys?

Comment: hmm.. i didn't understand why do you want such functionality? isn't it making your site less favorable?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this CSS:

```
user-select: none;
```

This makes the text on the site not selectable, so the user would not be able to highlight and copy any of it.

Additional information can also be found on this site here:

[How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Comment: But the user can invoke the context menu and then copy text.

Comment: @ArunAravind that is incorrect.   If the text cannot be highlighted, you cannot right-click and copy it.   You must be able to highlight the text first.

Comment: sorry for the downvote. That was a mistake. He said he wanted to have the save as menu. And user-select is not supported in older browsers.

Comment: In any case they would always have the option to "view source" and copy it that way. Not sure I see any point in this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
document.body.oncontextmenu = function(evt) { 
       // do custom menu stuff;
       evt.preventDefault();
}
```

this will disable the context menu as such.

This is supported in almost all browsers.
Then you may create a custom menu with "Save As" option. You could do this with pure css.

Comment: And you can disable the selection using user-select: none;

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect code if you dont want the users to select your text without diableing the right click

```
body
{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select:none;
        -o-user-select:none;
}
```